# Connect k3s agent outside the cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, k3s

I'm making a k3s cluster with oci, and the Oracle instances are connected well, but when I try to join the computer at home, the process stopped at the systemd: Starting k3s-agent part of the installation part.
Do I need to change the settings to join an external computer to k3s?

i tried to disable ufw, iptables, and opened vpc port for k3s agent, I tried similar in aws but the result was the same

Comment: First question would be: how does your computer at home connects to your cluster? Are you connected to a VPN, maybe? Are you sure your LAN is somehow connected to your cloud? Joining cluster requires 2-way connectivity between your node to cluster API: multi-site clusters would usually rely on VPN

Comment: I thought it would not matter if all k3s related ports were opened in oracle vpc firewall, and all k3s related ports were opened by port forwarding in my home router.
If I want to connect an external computer to the k3s, do I need to connect it to that K3s cluster's network via a vpn like wireguard?

Comment: Somethink like it, yes. Beyond API being able to connect to kubelet on all your nodes, you would often have an SDN which also assumes 2-way communications in between all nodes is possible, routing in-SDN connections. The most usual case is to deploy all nodes in the same LAN/vLAN. But if you want to do multi-site, a VPN would be easier.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.